# Call other file html with metro ui JS Dialog

Tags: javascript, html, metro-ui-css, metro.js

Guys do you know how to call external file for insert to dialog with Metro ui framework. I have followed docs here: http://metroui.org.ua/dialog.html 
But its not showing how to call external file like .html or .php. Please can you help me advice or solution.thanks

Comment: You can fetch the content with an AJAX call in `onShow` and set the returned data as content for dialog.

Comment: @anpsmn can you give link an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an ajax call and set the result as content for the dialog on `onShow` event. [[source]](http://metroui.org.ua/dialog.html)

```
$("#createFlatWindow").on('click', function(){
    $.Dialog({
        overlay: true,
        shadow: true,
        flat: true,
        icon: '<img src="images/excel2013icon.png">',
        title: 'Flat window',
        content: '',
        onShow: function(_dialog){
             $.ajax({
               url: "test.php", 
               dataType: "html",
               success: function(result){
                 var html = result;
                 $.Dialog.content(html);
               }
             });            
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: guys its great the external page successfull load, but why got error?the dialog cannot be closed.please help me im already confused

Comment: no problem guys, i forget to placed something.thanks for your helping